# Symfony 2 - Form for each instance of entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a Timeslot functionality where the user has to be able to edit the start and end of each slot.

So I would like to create one form that contains alle timeslots. I based my code on this article in symfony docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html
The problem is that in this article, there's some kind of parent entity to which the collection instances should be assigned to. In my case, the timeslots are standalone and do not have a relation with another entity (that is relevent at this stage).

So.. my question: How do I create a collection of forms with my timeslots?

Controller.php

```
/**
 * @Route("/settings", name="settings")
 * @Template()
 */
public function settingsAction()
{
    $timeslots = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("ScheduleBundle:Timeslot")->findAll();

    $timeslots_form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('timeslots', 'collection', array(
            'type'   => new TimeslotType(),
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    return array(
        'timeslots' => $timeslots_form->createView()
    );
}
```

TimeslotType.php:

```
class TimeslotType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('start', 'time', array(
                'input'  => 'datetime',
                'widget' => 'choice',
            ))
            ->add('end', 'time', array(
                'input'  => 'datetime',
                'widget' => 'choice',
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Oggi\ScheduleBundle\Entity\Timeslot'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'timeslot';
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass an array instead of an entity to your form.  The form can process either just fine.

```
$timeslots = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("ScheduleBundle:Timeslot")->findAll();

$formData = array('timeslots' => $timeslots);

$timeslots_form = $this->createFormBuilder($formData) ...
```