# Symfony nested form : how to edit value of a field

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a form named `Score` with multiple fields, from an entity.
I want to add another form, somewhere else in my project, to allow a quick edit of only 1 field of the Score entity, without the need to show the huge Score form (because other fields remain unchanged). I did a nested form  :

```
    $builder
    ->add('score', 'entity', array(
          'class' => 'AppBundle:Score',
          'choice_label' => 'value',
    ))

    ->add('save', 'submit');
```

It displays a choice list with value, but how to, instead of a choice list,  can i manage to directly edit the `value` field ? then when i press the save button, it persist the new value. When i try a `text` option, i've got an exception saying `text option` does not exist :

```
The option "text" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "cascade_validation", "choice_attr", "choice_label", "choice_list", "choice_loader", "choice_name", "choice_translation_domain", "choice_value", "choices", "choices_as_values", "class", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_provider", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "em", "empty_data", "empty_value", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "expanded", "extra_fields_message", "group_by", "id_reader", "inherit_data", "intention", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "loader", "mapped", "max_length", "method", "multiple", "pattern", "placeholder", "post_max_size_message", "preferred_choices", "property", "property_path", "query_builder", "read_only", "required", "translation_domain", "trim", "validation_groups", "virtual".
```

Comment: i found something interresting here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485325/symfony-2-form-for-each-instance-of-entity
Maybe it can help me, i'll come back anyway

Comment: it work now, i upvoted the other topic, thanks